# Multiple Tab Synchronization in Community Portal Using Loacal Storage

Tags: javascript, visualforce-component

I am working on visualforce community portal and there I need to synchronize the browser events across multiple tabs in order to capture auto logout function. The below code is working fine per each tab individually.

```
  function resetTime() {
          clearTimeout(t);
          window.clearTimeout(timeoutTimerID); 
          t = window.setTimeout(warningInactiveTime, sessionTime);  
        }
        
        
     function warningInactiveTime() {
             window.clearTimeout(t);
             timeoutTimerID = window.setTimeout(IdleTimeout, timoutNow);
           
            //   $('#timeOutWarningOverlay').show();
            $(".modalWrapperLogout").show();
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');    
            startTimer();
        }
        
        
     function idleLogoutFunction() {
            
            window.onload = resetTimer;
            window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
            window.onmousedown = resetTimer;  
            window.ontouchstart = resetTimer; 
            window.onclick = resetTimer;     
            window.onkeydown = resetTimer;   
            window.onkeyup = resetTimer;   
            window.addEventListener('onload', resetTimer, true);   
      }
```

Can someone help me to change this code in mutiple tab scenario using local storage?

Comment: Related: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_identity_redirect_expired_tabs.htm&type=5&release=232

Comment: @identigral Can this be used for community portals?

Comment: Don't know, it's a new feature. Sign up for a [Summer '21 preview sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000357271&type=1&mode=1) and give it a shot.